# Servlet 3.0 finalise?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

Is java servlet 3.0 finalised yet? I'm trying to implement comet and it would be a good idea to move on to Servlet 3.0. But I'm not sure if it'a way to move forward yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's finalised since 10 Dec 2009.

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is:

> Final Release: 10 Dec, 2009
>
> Status: Final

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315

Comment: Is it a good way to implement broadcasting server to a million users instead of WebSocket? I guess WebSocket has some compatibility issue with older browsers?

Comment: Please ask a separate question for that. And in the meantime have a look at https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere